# handle drop event in ol.interaction.DragAndDrop

Tags: openlayers-3

Why is non of the specified formatconstructors called for dragging and drop images on the map? I would like to write my own ol.format to read geotagged images (e.g. jpg), but the handled event has never an image file attached.
Thanks.